# Is there a way to select a row from a child repeater and insert it into a parent repeater row/fields in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, repeater

Ok, so I have this challenge and I'm still learning how things work in ASP C#. I have a parent update panel and inside that is a parent repeater. Inside that is a child update panel (not sure how necessary that is) and a child repeater. The Child repeater is for search results. When the user clicks on the textbox for entry of the parent repeater, an Ajax pop up occurs that allows them to search for the person they need in our LDAP AD system in the child updatepanel and when they enter a Last Name, First Name (or both) or an email and click "Search", the code behind does it's work, finds the results, populates the repeater and gets databound. I have this all happening in the parent OnItemCommand and it works. Here's my challenge - how in the world to I take the child row selected via button onclick and insert the data into the parent row items?

Here's my aspx code section, I apologize for the formatting:

```
<table class="project_info">    
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <dl>
                <dt>Project Stakeholders<br />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="sh_SHHeader" Text="Stakeholder" Width="314"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="sh_SHInput" Text="Input Level" Width="168"></asp:Label>
                </dt>
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="udp_SubProjectsTeamList" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ID="AddStakeholder" runat="server" OnItemCommand="AddStakeholder_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="AddStakeholder_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <dd>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_StakeholderId" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_StakeholderGUID" runat="server" />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Stakeholder" runat="server" Width="304" onkeyup="hasPendingChanges()" placeholder="Last Name, First Name" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MSStakeholder") %>'></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
                    <ajax:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="aj_AddStakeholder" PopupControlID="pnl_AddStakeholderChild" TargetControlID="txt_Stakeholder" CancelControlID="PopCancelButton" DropShadow="true" Y="50"></ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_SHInput" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" SelectedIndex='<%# Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"MSInput")) %>' Width="160" onchange="hasPendingChanges()">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Select Input Level" Value="0" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddAnother" runat="server" CssClass="k-button k-button-icontext repeaterbutton" Font-Size="small" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Button") %>' CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Button") %>' CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" CssClass="k-button k-button-icontext repeaterbutton" Font-Size="small" Font-Bold="false" Text='Reset' ToolTip="Reset Entry" OnClick="clearSHRow" CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>

                    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_AddStakeholderChild" runat="server" >
                    <div id="mainformdiv" class="k-widget k-window shPopup">
                        <div class="k-window-titlebar k-header">
                            <span class="k-window-title">Stakeholder Search<asp:Button ID="PopCancelButton" runat="server" CssClass="k-button k-button-icontext" Font-Size="small" CausesValidation="false" Text="X" style="float:right;" OnClientClick="this.form.reset();"/></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="k-popup-edit-form k-window-content k-content shPopupHead">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="udp_StakeholderSearch">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <div style="text-align:center;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_LastName" runat="server" CssClass="shLabel" Text="Last Name:"/><asp:TextBox ID="txt_LastName" runat="server" Width="200"/>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lbl_FirstName" runat="server" CssClass="shLabel" Text="First Name:"/><asp:TextBox ID="txt_FirstName" runat="server" Width="150"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;OR<asp:Label ID="lbl_Email" runat="server" CssClass="shLabel" Text="Email:"/><asp:TextBox ID="txt_Email" runat="server" Width="200"/>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Search"  runat="server" CssClass="k-button k-button-icontext" Text="Search" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Search"></asp:Button>
                                </div>
                                <asp:Repeater ID="rpt_SHSearchResults" runat="server">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                <div class="shPopupResults k-grid k-widget">
                                    <table>
                                        <thead class="k-grid-header">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th class="k-header" rowspan="1">Stakeholder Name</th>
                                                <th class="k-header" rowspan="1">Title</th>
                                                <th class="k-header" rowspan="1">Organization</th>
                                                <th class="k-header" rowspan="1">Email</th>
                                                <th class="k-header" rowspan="1"></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="samaccountname" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("userName") %>'/>
                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="objectGUID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("userGUID") %>'/>
                                            <tr class="k-alt">
                                                <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="name" Text='<%# Eval("FullName") %>' /></td>
                                                <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="title" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' /></td>
                                                <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="company" Text='<%# Eval("Company") %>' /></td>                                
                                                <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="email" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>' /></td>
                                                <td style="text-align: center;width:auto"><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_SHSelect" CssClass="k-button k-button-icontext" Text="Select" CausesValidation="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/></td>
                                            </tr>                            
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>    
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnl_EmptyList" runat="server" Visible="false">
                                <div class="shEmptyResults k-grid k-widget">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr class="k-alt">
                                            <td colspan="5">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_EmptyList" runat="server" BorderWidth="0"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                </asp:Panel>
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnl_Results" runat="server" Visible="false">
                                <div class="shPopupHead">
                                    <span class="k-window-title"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="resultCount" style="float:left;" /></span>
                                </div>                                                
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="udp_SearchProgress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="udp_StakeholderSearch">
                            <ProgressTemplate>
                                <div class="shEmptyResults k-grid k-widget">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr class="k-alt">
                                            <td colspan="5" style="background:#fff"><img src="env/images/searching.gif" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </ProgressTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdateProgress>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </dd>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </dl>
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

And the .cs code behind:

```
protected void AddStakeholder_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Search")
    {
        string last_name = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt_LastName")).Text;
        string first_name = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt_FirstName")).Text;
        string email = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt_Email")).Text;
        TextBox test = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt_Email"));

        string searchFilter = "";

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(last_name) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(first_name) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
        {
            searchFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(company=*)(sn=" + last_name + ")(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))";
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(last_name) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(first_name) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
        {
            searchFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(company=*)(sn=" + last_name + ")(givenName=" + first_name + ")(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))";
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
        {
            searchFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(company=*)(userPrincipalName=" + email + ")(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))";
        }
        //output.Text = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)" + searchFilter + ")";
        DirectoryEntry domain = new DirectoryEntry("my company's LDAP server information");
        DirectorySearcher dsLookFor = new DirectorySearcher(domain)
        {
            SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
            Filter = searchFilter
        };
        //dsLookFor.Filter = searchFilter;
        dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
        dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectGUID");
        dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
        dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("title");
        dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("company");
        dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userPrincipalName");
        dsLookFor.Sort.Direction = System.DirectoryServices.SortDirection.Ascending;
        dsLookFor.Sort.PropertyName = "name";

        SearchResultCollection result = dsLookFor.FindAll();
        int totalCount = result.Count;
        var users = result.Cast<SearchResult>().Select(sr => sr.GetDirectoryEntry()).Select(de => new
        {
            userName = de.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value != null ? protectSpecialChar((string)de.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value) : "",
            userGUID = de.Properties["objectGUID"].Value != null ? new Guid((byte[])de.Properties["objectGUID"].Value).ToString() : "",
            FullName = de.Properties["name"].Value != null ? protectSpecialChar((string)de.Properties["name"].Value) : "",
            Title = de.Properties["title"].Value != null ? protectSpecialChar((string)de.Properties["title"].Value) : "",
            Company = de.Properties["company"].Value != null ? protectSpecialChar((string)de.Properties["company"].Value) : "",
            Email = de.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value != null ? protectSpecialChar((string)de.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value) : "",
        }).ToList();

        if (totalCount == 0)
        {
            ((Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnl_EmptyList")).Visible = true;
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbl_EmptyList")).Text = "No results to display. Please check your entries and try again.";
        }
        else
        {
            rpt_SHSearchResults.DataSource = users;
            rpt_SHSearchResults.DataBind();
            rpt_SHSearchResults.Visible = true;
            ((Panel)e.Item.FindControl("pnl_Results")).Visible = true;
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("resultCount")).Text = "Result count: " + totalCount;
        }
    }
}
protected void AddStakeholder_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HiddenField hdn_StakeholderId = e.Item.FindControl("hdn_StakeholderId") as HiddenField;
        HiddenField hdn_StakeholderGUID = e.Item.FindControl("hdn_StakeholderGUID") as HiddenField;
        TextBox txt_Stakeholder = e.Item.FindControl("txt_Stakeholder") as TextBox;
        DropDownList drp_SHInput = e.Item.FindControl("drp_SHInput") as DropDownList;
        DataSet shInputSet = new DataSet();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["webconfig entry"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            //Contractor List dropdown
            SqlDataAdapter shInput = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT StakeholderInputId,InputName FROM StakeholderInput", con);
            shInput.Fill(shInputSet);
            drp_SHInput.DataSource = shInputSet;
            drp_SHInput.DataTextField = "InputName";
            drp_SHInput.DataValueField = "StakeholderInputId";
            drp_SHInput.DataBind();

            con.Close();
        }
        Repeater shSearchResults = e.Item.FindControl("rpt_SHSearchResults") as Repeater;
        HiddenField userName = shSearchResults.FindControl("samaccountname") as HiddenField;
        HiddenField userGUID = shSearchResults.FindControl("objectGUID") as HiddenField;
        Label name = shSearchResults.FindControl("name") as Label;
        Label title = shSearchResults.FindControl("title") as Label;
        Label company = shSearchResults.FindControl("company") as Label;
        Label email = shSearchResults.FindControl("email") as Label;
    }
}
```

Should I have a OnClick="dosomethinghere" on the child repeater button "Select" and then take the child row information and attempt to inject it into the parent controls? How would that be accomplished?

I've tried everything I can think of to make this work, and I've done countless searches in Google and SO and elsewhere to see if anyone else has solved this issue. I'm about an intermediate level coder and this one has me stumped. How do I get the selected result row from the child repeater into the parent row?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Could you reduce your code example to the minimum your question needs to be answered please ?

Comment: I've removed some unnecessary code from the .cs portion.